# How to combine digits to a number

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a calculator on my website so i'm using HTML & Javascript . I added some buttons and when i click it changes the number and it's not adding it after the last element.

**Here's what it looks like :**

[image]

As you can see it just replaces the number.

**Here's my code :**

```js
function onClick(num) {
  document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = num;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Enter number(s) :
    <a id="number"></a>
  </p>

  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(7)">7</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(8)">8</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(9)">9</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(4)">4</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(5)">5</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(6)">6</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(1)">1</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(2)">2</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(3)">3</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick('=')">=</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(0)">0</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick('.')">.</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Oh and i'm not asking any code i'm just asking for a little hint on how to do what i want. And yes i've been looking on the internet but i didn't find what i wanted.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could concatenate the `innerHTML` with `+=` so that it doesn't overwrite the existing `innerHTML`.

**Working example:**

```js
function onClick(num) {
  document.getElementById('number').innerHTML += num;
}
```

```css
#calculator {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #549699;
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
  <p>Enter number(s) :
    <a id="number"></a>
  </p>
  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(7)">7</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(8)">8</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(9)">9</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(4)">4</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(5)">5</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(6)">6</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(1)">1</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(2)">2</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(3)">3</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick('=')">=</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(0)">0</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick('.')">.</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Basic calculator:**

With `window[operation]()` you can call a function with `operation` as function name. For example `window['multiply']()` is the same like `multiply()`.

```js
const output = document.getElementById('number');
let operation = '';
let temp_result = 0;

function onClick(num) {
  output.innerHTML += num;
}

function divide(a, b) {
  return a / b;
}

function multiply(a, b) {
  return a * b;
}

function subtract(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

function addNumber(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

function chooseOperation(choice) {
  operation = choice;
  temp_result = parseFloat(output.innerHTML);
  output.innerHTML = '';
}

function startCalculation() {
  if (operation != '') {
    let operator = parseFloat(output.innerHTML)
    output.innerHTML = window[operation](temp_result, operator);
  }
  operation = '';
}
```

```css
#calculator {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #549699;
}

button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 2px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
  <p>Enter number(s) :
    <a id="number"></a>
  </p>
  
  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(7)">7</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(8)">8</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(9)">9</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="chooseOperation('divide')">/</button>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(4)">4</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(5)">5</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(6)">6</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="chooseOperation('multiply')">*</button>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(1)">1</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(2)">2</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(3)">3</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="chooseOperation('subtract')">-</button>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="startCalculation()">=</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick(0)">0</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick('.')">.</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="chooseOperation('addNumber')">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Advanced calculator:**

```js
const output = document.getElementById('number');
let operation = '';
let temp_result = 0;

function addChar(num) {
  if (output.innerHTML == 0) {
    output.innerHTML = num;
  }
  else {
    output.innerHTML += num;
  }
}

function divide(a, b) {
  return a / b;
}

function multiply(a, b) {
  return a * b;
}

function subtract(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

function addNumber(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

function calculate() {
  if (operation != '') {
    let operator = parseFloat(output.innerHTML)
    output.innerHTML = window[operation](temp_result, operator);
  }
}

function chooseOperation(choice) {
  calculate();
  operation = choice;
  temp_result = parseFloat(output.innerHTML);
  output.innerHTML = 0;
}

function startCalculation() {
  calculate();
  operation = '';
}

function reset() {
  output.innerHTML = 0;
  operation = '';
}
```

```css
#calculator {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 95px;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background-color: #549699;
}

#number {
  width: 96%;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  text-align: end;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 2px 0;
}

#reset {
  width: 96%;
}

#reset button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
  <span id="number">0</span>
  
  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="addChar('7')">7</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="addChar('8')">8</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="addChar('9')">9</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="chooseOperation('divide')">/</button>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="addChar('4')">4</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="addChar('5')">5</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="addChar('6')">6</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="chooseOperation('multiply')">*</button>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="addChar('1')">1</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="addChar('2')">2</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="addChar('3')">3</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="chooseOperation('subtract')">-</button>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="startCalculation()">=</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="addChar('0')">0</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="addChar('.')">.</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="chooseOperation('addNumber')">+</button>
  </div>
  
  <div id="reset">
    <button type="button" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: to make it calculate you can do `document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = Number(document.getElementById('number').innerHTML) + num;`

Comment: *it's not adding it after the last element* -> he wants to write a number with more than just one digit - nothing about calculation so far...

Comment: ty a lot for your answers !

Comment: @SirTristanus I added an example with calculation. Please give a feedback...

Comment: it's not what i was going to do but it looks interesting ty for your help

Answer (score 0):

It just replaces the the current innerHTML value by the value you clicked. You should save the current value of `document.getElementById('number').innerHTML` in another variable and add your new `num` value to that variable. Then you can set the sum as the new innerHTML value.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<script>
//function for displaying values
function dis(val)
{
document.getElementById("edu").value+=val
 }
//function for evaluation
function solve()
{
let x = document.getElementById("edu").value
let y = eval(x)
document.getElementById("edu").value = y
}
//function for clearing the display
function clr()
{
document.getElementById("edu").value = ""
}
</script>

<div class="title">Made by Yasin</div>
<table border="1">
<tbody><tr>
<td><input type="button" value="c" onclick="clr()"> </td>
<td colspan="3"><input type="text" id="edu"></td>
<!-- clr() function will call clr to clear all value -->
</tr>
<tr>
<!-- creating buttons and assigning values-->
<td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="dis('+')"> </td>
<td><input type="button" value="1" onclick="dis('1')"> </td>
<td><input type="button" value="2" onclick="dis('2')"> </td>
<td><input type="button" value="3" onclick="dis('3')"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" value="-" onclick="dis('-')"> </td>
<td><input type="button" value="4" onclick="dis('4')"> </td>
<td><input type="button" value="5" onclick="dis('5')"> </td>
<td><input type="button" value="6" onclick="dis('6')"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" value="*" onclick="dis('*')"> </td>
<td><input type="button" value="7" onclick="dis('7')"> </td>
<td><input type="button" value="8" onclick="dis('8')"> </td>
<td><input type="button" value="9" onclick="dis('9')"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" value="/" onclick="dis('/')"> </td>
<td><input type="button" value="." onclick="dis('.')"> </td>
<td><input type="button" value="0" onclick="dis('0')"> </td>
<!-- Evaluating function call eval()-->
<td><input type="button" value="=" onclick="solve()"> </td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>

<!-- for styling -->
<style>
.title{
border-radius: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
text-align:center;
width: 210px;
color:#ff4456;
border: solid black 1px;
}
input[type="button"]
{
border-radius: 10px;
background-color:#ff4456;
color: black;
border-color:#ff4456 ;
width:100%;
}
input[type="text"]
{
border-radius: 10px;
text-align: right;
background-color:white;
border-color: black ;
width:100%
}
</style>
```